# How do I wait for a background login before trying to make more requests IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have been building a framework for my employer to abstract the network requests and our authentication away from the developers that will be contributing to our application. We are using forms authentication for our web api's (I wish I could change it) When my application launches my framework checks and makes sure my cookie is not expired and if it is I try to log in so the user has a seamless experience. I am encountering an issue where if the cookie is expired and I request a new one sometimes it takes a little bit of time (especially on 3G) so while I am logging the user in sometimes they select an option that needs network data and the request is sent with an invalid cookie. What is the best way to have a request wait until I have finished logging in before making the request. here is some pseudo code

```
IF appIsLoggingIn
WAIT FOR COMPLETION
WHEN COMPLETED PROCEED
ELSE
PROCEED AS NORMAL
```

Comment: Why don't you add a view to cover the entire screen, to prevent the user from doing anything, while the authentication takes place in the background. Have a Spinner and text label with something like 'Authentication in progress' while the connection is made. Use NSNotification to remove the view once everything has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

A completion block would be suitable for this.

```
+ (void)login:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error))completionBlock;
{
    ...

    // Do some NSURLRequests here and when you get the
    //  response, call the completionBlock

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        completionBlock(@{ @"some-key":@"some-response-value-from-server" }, nil);
    });
}
```

You can also use a BOOL completion block instead of a void, so when the server returns that the login is successful, the BOOL can return TRUE.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what this is supposed to do and how it would cause a request to a server to wait until I am done logging in. I already have a delegate in place that will notify that I am logged in but the problem lies when a request needs to be made to a server while the login is still in process.